# Download Image from HTML WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

Below is one of the tag i'm getting from a URL which is loaded in WKWebView

> < img id="image_id" name="imageName" src="captcha.jpg">

On DidFinish is it possible to get that image as UIImage ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve this I've used some libraries to help.

In your project using pod (or carthage or whatever you like) insert the following libraries:

[SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup)

[AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)

Once your project is set with those libs here we go.

In your storyboard, place 2 elements, in mine I have one WKWebView and below one ImageView.
Just set the constraints to be sure everything will be on screen when testing.

[image]

Then in the code we will have:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import SwiftSoup
import AlamofireImage


class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let urlReq = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 1)
        webView!.load(urlReq)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()",
                                   completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
                                    do{
                                        let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html as! String)
                                        let pngs: Elements = try doc.select("img[src$=.png]")
                                        let srcsStringArray: [String?] = pngs.array().map { try? $0.attr("src").description }
                                        for imgs in srcsStringArray {
                                            if let imgUrl = imgs {
                                                var finalUrl = URL(string: "")
                                                if imgUrl.contains("http") {
                                                    finalUrl = URL(string: String(format: imgUrl))
                                                } else {
                                                    finalUrl = URL(string: String(format: "%@%@", (self.url?.absoluteString)!, imgUrl))
                                                }
                                                self.imageView.af_setImage(withURL: finalUrl!)
                                                print(finalUrl) //debug URL
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch Exception.Error(let type, let message){
                                        print(type, message)
                                    } catch {
                                        print("error")
                                    }
        })
    }
}
```

This example works AS IS.

Sure, you need to adapt it to your needs, but you have all elements to do so.

**EDIT 1:**

There I have just one image, if you have more than one image you must handle it properly on lines:

`for imgs in srcsStringArray {...}`

**EDIT 2:**

Captcha ready, getting the exact loaded image.
In this case you don't need *Alamofire* nor *SwiftSoup*

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    let url = URL(string: "YOUR_URL")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let urlReq = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 1)
        webView!.load(urlReq)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        let str = "var c = document.createElement('canvas'); var ctx = c.getContext('2d'); ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('captcha_id'), 100, 40); var value = c.toDataURL(); value.split(',')[1]; "

        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(str) { (value, error) in
             if error == nil {
                 if let img = value as? String {
                      self.imageView.image = self.base64ToImage(base64: img)
                 }
             }
         }
    }

    func base64ToImage(base64: String) -> UIImage? {
        var img: UIImage = UIImage()
        if (!base64.isEmpty) {
            if let decodedData = NSData(base64Encoded: base64 , options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
                if let decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData as Data) {
                    img = (decodedimage as UIImage?)!
                    return img
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the same image which is loaded in WebView at that URL? The problem is I have captcha on that screen so if I hit the URL again then that image is changed.

Comment: "Is it possible to get the same image which is loaded in WebView at that URL?" the code do exact what you're asking. "The problem is I have captcha on that screen so if I hit the URL again then that image is changed" it shouldn't happen as the code takes the HTML code loaded and don't do any other post on the page. But the solution answer your question, you didn't mention anything about captcha. Particularities must be handled in your code. Please, accept the answer if it helped

Comment: Yes GIJOW. You solution is absolutely correct. Just wanted to know in this scenario how we handle? Captcha image changes on every hit so when I hits the URL for the first time then the captcha loaded is different than the one in imageView as AlamofireImage hits that captcha URL again which generates a new one.

Comment: Can you give the site you're hitting to get the image ? I can try to make some tests here

Comment: will have a look and get back

Comment: New edit for you buddy. Hope you accept the answer now

Comment: Thanks a lot. You put lots of effort. It solved my problem exactly. Appreciate your work.

Comment: how to do this if image is like <td>                                          
                                <img style="height: 50px;width: 190px;" src="/memberinterface/no-auth/captcha/createCaptcha?_HDIV_STATE_=13-4-EEA1DDAD1676E8AE6522CFCBC63FEB44">
                            </td>

Comment: Same way. You must be able to get elements by some unique key/value using one of this http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html then you replace the command on my code `document.getElementById('captcha_id')` by your `get....` and value

Comment: So in this I have to use getElementsByTagName("img") ?

Comment: You can, then you must handle properly if you have more than one `img` tag in your html

Comment: How to handle that ? I have 2 img tag. I need 2nd one.

Comment: replace by this line in the code above: `let str = "var c = document.createElement('canvas'); var ctx = c.getContext('2d'); const list = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); ctx.drawImage(list[1], 100, 40); var value = c.toDataURL(); value.split(',')[1]; "`

Comment: This answer was fantastic. Thank you so much.